# Classified ads with tcolor box

Tags: tcolorbox, multirow

I am trying to make a classified ads paper in LaTex using tcolor box. I am new to this so please be patient with me. Here is a screenshot of what I am trying to emulate.

[image: Example classified ad that I am trying to emulate]

Here is what I have been able to create so far:

[image: tcolor box attempt to generate classified ads]

I need to be able to have a single line between each ad with minimum spacing and an invisible border on either side. Please suggest how I can modify the code or if there is better code I should be using. Thank you.

Here is my LaTeX .tex code:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ {../images/} } 



\begin{document}
\section{Example}
An early version of an example document that eventually will render classified ads using \LaTeX , tcolorbox and multirow. Possibly ltablex too.
The page below is an example image of the look we are aiming for. The third page is going to attempt to render using LaTeX and specific extensions.

\includegraphics{exampleclassified.ps}

\section{First try example}

\begin{tcbraster}[raster equal height=rows,raster every box/.style={colframe=black!50!black,colback=white}]\begin{tcolorbox}[blankest]\begin{tcbraster}[raster columns=1]\begin{tcolorbox}[natural height,
        space to upper,
        skin=bicolor,
        colbacklower=black!95,
        collower=white,
        title={X-should be blank and the same dimensions as the orginal },
        halign=center,
        valign=center,
        nobeforeafter,
        halign lower=flush right,
        bottom=0mm,
        height=3cm
    ]


        \$ CASH \$ For Broken Autos.
        Paying \$50 to \$500. I Tow!
        Call Doug Anytime 7-Days,
        (269)501-5763.\end{tcolorbox}
        \begin{tcolorbox}
        \$ \$ \$ WE BUY USED \& Unwanted Autos.
        Any condition, Top \$ \$ \$
        paid. Will pick up Free.
        Airway Auto Parts
        (269)962-9521

        \end{tcolorbox}

        \begin{tcolorbox}

        \$500! POLICE IMPOUNDS!
        Hondas/Chevys/Jeeps!
        Cars from \$500! For listings:
        800-619-3790 ext.2938
        \end{tcolorbox}

        \end{tcbraster}\end{tcolorbox}\end{tcbraster}



\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the initial proposal was done with `tcolorbox`, here you have two possible solutions with `tcolorbox`. As OP already proposed these solutions are based on `tcbraster`. The first one uses a one-column-tcbraster inside a multicol environment and the second uses a three-column-tcbraster.

Inner boxes are defined in `classified` style and they are `blank` boxes with added upper and lower margins and a bottom borderline.

That's all!

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{multicol}

\tcbset{classified/.style={enhanced, blanker, borderline south={2pt}{0pt}{black}, top=1mm, bottom=1mm}}
\begin{document}

\begin{multicols}{3}
\begin{tcbitemize}[raster columns=1, raster row skip = 0pt, classified]
\tcbitem \$ CASH \$ For Broken Autos. Paying \$50 to \$500. I Tow! Call Doug Anytime 7-Days, (269)501-5763.
\tcbitem \$ \$ \$ WE BUY USED \& Unwanted Autos. Any condition, Top \$ \$ \$ paid. Will pick up Free. Airway Auto Parts (269)962-9521
\tcbitem \$500! POLICE IMPOUNDS! Hondas/Chevys/Jeeps! Cars from \$500! For listings: 800-619-3790 ext.2938
\tcbitem \$ CASH \$ For Broken Autos. Paying \$50 to \$500. I Tow! Call Doug Anytime 7-Days, (269)501-5763.
\tcbitem \$ \$ \$ WE BUY USED \& Unwanted Autos. Any condition, Top \$ \$ \$ paid. Will pick up Free. Airway Auto Parts (269)962-9521
\tcbitem \$500! POLICE IMPOUNDS! Hondas/Chevys/Jeeps! Cars from \$500! For listings: 800-619-3790 ext.2938
\tcbitem \$ CASH \$ For Broken Autos. Paying \$50 to \$500. I Tow! Call Doug Anytime 7-Days, (269)501-5763.
\tcbitem \$ \$ \$ WE BUY USED \& Unwanted Autos. Any condition, Top \$ \$ \$ paid. Will pick up Free. Airway Auto Parts (269)962-9521
\tcbitem \$500! POLICE IMPOUNDS! Hondas/Chevys/Jeeps! Cars from \$500! For listings: 800-619-3790 ext.2938
\tcbitem \$ CASH \$ For Broken Autos. Paying \$50 to \$500. I Tow! Call Doug Anytime 7-Days, (269)501-5763.
\tcbitem \$ \$ \$ WE BUY USED \& Unwanted Autos. Any condition, Top \$ \$ \$ paid. Will pick up Free. Airway Auto Parts (269)962-9521
\tcbitem \$500! POLICE IMPOUNDS! Hondas/Chevys/Jeeps! Cars from \$500! For listings: 800-619-3790 ext.2938
\tcbitem \$ CASH \$ For Broken Autos. Paying \$50 to \$500. I Tow! Call Doug Anytime 7-Days, (269)501-5763.
\tcbitem \$ \$ \$ WE BUY USED \& Unwanted Autos. Any condition, Top \$ \$ \$ paid. Will pick up Free. Airway Auto Parts (269)962-9521
\tcbitem \$500! POLICE IMPOUNDS! Hondas/Chevys/Jeeps! Cars from \$500! For listings: 800-619-3790 ext.2938
\tcbitem \$ CASH \$ For Broken Autos. Paying \$50 to \$500. I Tow! Call Doug Anytime 7-Days, (269)501-5763.
\tcbitem \$ \$ \$ WE BUY USED \& Unwanted Autos. Any condition, Top \$ \$ \$ paid. Will pick up Free. Airway Auto Parts (269)962-9521
\end{tcbitemize}
\end{multicols}

\begin{tcbitemize}[raster columns=3, raster row skip = 0pt, raster equal height=rows, classified]
\tcbitem \$ CASH \$ For Broken Autos. Paying \$50 to \$500. I Tow! Call Doug Anytime 7-Days, (269)501-5763.
\tcbitem \$ \$ \$ WE BUY USED \& Unwanted Autos. Any condition, Top \$ \$ \$ paid. Will pick up Free. Airway Auto Parts (269)962-9521
\tcbitem \$500! POLICE IMPOUNDS! Hondas/Chevys/Jeeps! Cars from \$500! For listings: 800-619-3790 ext.2938
\tcbitem \$ CASH \$ For Broken Autos. Paying \$50 to \$500. I Tow! Call Doug Anytime 7-Days, (269)501-5763.
\tcbitem \$ \$ \$ WE BUY USED \& Unwanted Autos. Any condition, Top \$ \$ \$ paid. Will pick up Free. Airway Auto Parts (269)962-9521
\tcbitem \$500! POLICE IMPOUNDS! Hondas/Chevys/Jeeps! Cars from \$500! For listings: 800-619-3790 ext.2938
\tcbitem \$ CASH \$ For Broken Autos. Paying \$50 to \$500. I Tow! Call Doug Anytime 7-Days, (269)501-5763.
\tcbitem \$ \$ \$ WE BUY USED \& Unwanted Autos. Any condition, Top \$ \$ \$ paid. Will pick up Free. Airway Auto Parts (269)962-9521
\tcbitem \$500! POLICE IMPOUNDS! Hondas/Chevys/Jeeps! Cars from \$500! For listings: 800-619-3790 ext.2938
\tcbitem \$ CASH \$ For Broken Autos. Paying \$50 to \$500. I Tow! Call Doug Anytime 7-Days, (269)501-5763.
\tcbitem \$ \$ \$ WE BUY USED \& Unwanted Autos. Any condition, Top \$ \$ \$ paid. Will pick up Free. Airway Auto Parts (269)962-9521
\tcbitem \$500! POLICE IMPOUNDS! Hondas/Chevys/Jeeps! Cars from \$500! For listings: 800-619-3790 ext.2938
\tcbitem \$ CASH \$ For Broken Autos. Paying \$50 to \$500. I Tow! Call Doug Anytime 7-Days, (269)501-5763.
\tcbitem \$ \$ \$ WE BUY USED \& Unwanted Autos. Any condition, Top \$ \$ \$ paid. Will pick up Free. Airway Auto Parts (269)962-9521
\tcbitem \$500! POLICE IMPOUNDS! Hondas/Chevys/Jeeps! Cars from \$500! For listings: 800-619-3790 ext.2938
\tcbitem \$ CASH \$ For Broken Autos. Paying \$50 to \$500. I Tow! Call Doug Anytime 7-Days, (269)501-5763.
\tcbitem \$ \$ \$ WE BUY USED \& Unwanted Autos. Any condition, Top \$ \$ \$ paid. Will pick up Free. Airway Auto Parts (269)962-9521
\end{tcbitemize}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Ignasi, this is a beautiful and elegant solution. I am very impressed. It looks like I have a choice now.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what you want your whole page to look like, but a you might consider using a minipage just with a line separating your ads. Something like this.  I added just random text in the other minipages, but you could continue to add more lines between each one.  Again, I'm not sure if this is what you are looking for, but it might be a place to start and do more research:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ {../images/} } 


\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.3\textwidth}
 \$ CASH \$ For Broken Autos.
        Paying \$50 to \$500. I Tow!
        Call Doug Anytime 7-Days,
        (269)501-5763. 
        \noindent\rule{3.8cm}{0.8pt}

         \$ CASH \$ For Broken Autos.
        Paying \$50 to \$500. I Tow!
        Call Doug Anytime 7-Days,
        (269)501-5763. 
        \noindent\rule{3.8cm}{0.8pt}

         \$ CASH \$ For Broken Autos.
        Paying \$50 to \$500. I Tow!
        Call Doug Anytime 7-Days,
        (269)501-5763. 
        \noindent\rule{3.8cm}{0.8pt}

This is a test.  This is a test.  This is a test.  This is a test.  This is a test.  This is a test  This is a test.  This is a test.  This is a test  This is a test.  This is a test.  This is a test  This is a test.  This is a test.  This is a test
\end{minipage}
\hspace{0.5cm}
%%%%%
%%%%%
%%%%%
%%%%%
%%%%%
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.3\textwidth}
This is a test.  This is a test.  This is a test.  This is a test.  This is a test.  This is a test  This is a test.  This is a test.  This is a test  This is a test.  This is a test.  This is a test  This is a test.  This is a test.  This is a test
\end{minipage}
\hspace{0.5cm}
%%%%%
%%%%%
%%%%%
%%%%%
%%%%%
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.3\textwidth}
This is a test.  This is a test.  This is a test.  This is a test.  This is a test.  This is a test  This is a test.  This is a test.  This is a test  This is a test.  This is a test.  This is a test  This is a test.  This is a test.  This is a test
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

[image: Example]

Comment: Hi Danny, 

The simple solutions are often the best. I didn't know about minipage and mini-par before this. They may work very well for most of the classified ads but I can still use tcolorbox for larger more prominent ads. Thank you very much. I will try them out.